# Trigger workflow when a file is added into a specific library

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I use SharePoint Online and SharePoint Designer. I would like to Trigger a workflow when a document is added into a document library. I guess this is possible but I dont see how, since i'm new to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open your site in SharePoint Designer
2. Click *Lists and Libraries* in the navigation pane on the left
3. Click your document library to open it
4. From the ribbon click *List Workflow*
5. Give your workflow a name and a description
6. Start building your workflow and save it
7. Click *Workflows* in the navigation pane on the left
8. Click your newly created workflow to open it
9. Under the *Start Options* section check the box that says *Start workflow automatically when an item is created* and uncheck the other boxes
10. Save and publish your workflow